# SQL SUM OVER PARTITION BY 2 columns not working

Tags: sql, oracle, partition-by

Common question, I know. Just haven't been able to find a solution to my question, so hit me with the removal and or downvotes if you must.

(Oracle 12c)

I have data that looks like this:

```
Date        ITEM   QTY

01-MAR-20   STS    6920
01-MAR-20   STS    2581
01-MAR-20   S01    22606
01-MAR-20   S01    22312
01-MAR-20   S01    56000
....
```

I want to get QTY to aggregate (sum) at the Date and item level with only one record for each unique item on each date, so it looks like this:

```
Date        ITEM   QTY
01-MAR-20   STS    9501
01-MAR-20   S01    100918
```

The query I'm trying to use to do this is:

```
SELECT 

WO.DATE,
D.ITEM,
SUM(WO.QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY WO.DATE, D.ITEM) AS QTY

FROM SCHEMA_1.WO,
SCHEMA_2.D

WHERE WO.ITEM_DIM_KEY = D.ITEM_DIM_KEY AND
(DATE > '01 MAR 2020' AND DATE < '01 JUL 2020')
ORDER BY WO.COMPLETED_DATE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `date` data type in Oracle can have a time component.  So you need to be careful.  Unless you *know* hat you have no time component, `trunc()` is safer.  Also, you can use the `date` keyword to handle date constants:
SELECT

```
SELECT TRUNC(WO.DATE), D.ITEM,
       SUM(WO.QUANTITY)
FROM SCHEMA_1.WO JOIN
     SCHEMA_2.D
     ON WO.ITEM_DIM_KEY = D.ITEM_DIM_KEY 
WHERE WO.DATE >= DATE '2020-03-01' AND
      WO.DATE < DATE '2020-07-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(WO.DATE), D.ITEM
ORDER BY TRUNC(WO.DATE);
```

Notes:

- You don't need an analytic function. Aggregation should be sufficient.
- Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- I assume the column in the `ORDER BY` is intended to be the first column in the result set.

Comment: I appreciate the help and the pointers. I'm thinking it was just the date issue because I tried using aggregation through a group by clause before posting this.

Comment: @Gordon You are missing D.ITEM from your group by.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    WO.DATE,
    D.ITEM,
    SUM(WO.QUANTITY) AS QTY
FROM SCHEMA_1.WO
INNER JOIN SCHEMA_2.D
    ON WO.ITEM_DIM_KEY = D.ITEM_DIM_KEY
WHERE
    DATE > '01 MAR 2020' AND DATE < '01 JUL 2020'
GROUP BY
    WO.DATE,
    D.ITEM
ORDER BY
    WO.COMPLETED_DATE;
```

Using `SUM` as a window function would make sense if you wanted to retain every record in the result set of the join.  However, in your case, you want to report *aggregate* sums for each date/item group.  Using `GROUP BY` is what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a simple aggregation:

```
select trunc(date), item, sum(qty) 
from schema_1.wo
join schema_2.d on wo.item_dim_key = d.item_dim_key 
where date > date '2020-03-01' and date < date '2020-07-01'
group by trunc(date), item
order by wo.completed_date
```

Incidentally, I upgraded the `JOIN` to SQL-92 and fixed the dates literal to ISO dates instead of `VARCHAR`s.